Combining information from different quantiles
I have a number of "mostly" Gaussian distributions (in truth a Gauss core and longer tails). I am interested in the width of this distributions.
Given that I do not know the amount of tails and that ultimately I am comparing with models that are valid for different inner quantiles, I am estimating the width of these distributions using different estimators (RMS, MAD, ...). I am combining the different estimators (as shown for example here: https://hal.science/hal-00936024v4/file/A-general-procedure-to-combine-estimators.pdf) and get per quantile a value with its associated error.
The values and their errors are shown below. A quantile of 90 would mean that I consider the inner 90% quantile, throwing away 5% of the tail data on the left and 5% on the right.



quantile
value
error




80
0.376
0.012


85
0.379
0.011


90
0.378
0.012


93
0.39
0.012


95
0.389
0.013


97
0.396
0.014


98
0.39
0.015


99
0.394
0.017


100
0.39
0.016



My question is now: how can I combine the values and the associated errors from the different quantiles in the hopes of getting a smaller error? Can it be done? Are there any caveats? Are the errors correlated?

What do you mean by estimating width via RMS estimator? Are the distributions you mention available as PDF/PDF or do you have realizations?

I have a distribution that is a convolution of a Gauss and a Student's t (or at least this describes the data best) -- see for example here: https://i.sstatic.net/f5PCE2I6.png
I can select a specific inner part of the distribution via the quantile (eg: 90% means I only consider the inner 90% part and disregard the 5% left and 5% right tails).
Then, I have multiple estimators at my disposal to express the width of the distribution. One of them is the RMS. I am studying which distribution is most robust and stable as a function of decreasing quantile.
